# Como escoger del dropdown y que me salga si ya existe en la base de datos y se limpie el input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Ayuda por favor cuando escribo directamente en el input y existe una orden igua en la base de datos se limpia el input y muestra una notificacion pero cuando selecciono una orden del dropdown pero ya existe simplemente no me muestra la notificacion ayuda por favor

**este es el codigo donde escojo del dropdown y lo imprimo en el input**

```
/*==================================
OBTENER EL VALOR DEL DROPDOWN E IMPRIMIRLO EN EL INPUT
==================================*/
$(document).on("click", "#opcionesCodigoOrdenTrabajo > a", setDropdownValue);

function setDropdownValue() {

    let option = $(this);

    option.closest(".input-group").find("input").val(option.text());

}
```

**este es el codigo que uso para que me verifique cuando digito manualmente en el input sin seleccionar en el dropdown**

```
/*=============================
REVISAR SI LA ORDEN DE TRABAJO YA HA SIDO REGISTRADA
=============================*/
$('#codigoOrdenTrabajo').change(function () {

    let ordenTrabajo = $(this).val(),
        datos = new FormData();

    //name: = adicionar variable POST
    datos.append('validarOrdenTrabajo', ordenTrabajo);

    $.ajax({

        url: "ajax/transacciones_ajax.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: datos,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (respuesta) {

            if (respuesta) {

                toastr.error(
                    'El numero de orden ya existe en la base de datos',
                    '',
                    {
                        timeOut: 1000,
                        fadeOut: 1000,
                    }
                );
                $('#codigoOrdenTrabajo').val("");

            }

            //REVISAR LO QUE VIENE DESDE LA BDD
            console.log("respuesta", respuesta);

        }
    });
});
```

**este es el html donde se encuentra el dropdown donde obtengo los valores por medio de php de las ordenes de trabajo ya creadas**

```
<td style="vertical-align: middle">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="text"
                                               class="form-control"
                                               name="codigoOrdenTrabajo"
                                               id="codigoOrdenTrabajo"
                                               minlength="5"
                                               maxlength="5"
                                               required>
                                        <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <button type="button"
                                                    class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle"
                                                    data-toggle="dropdown"
                                                    aria-expanded="false">
                                            </button>
                                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"
                                                 id="opcionesCodigoOrdenTrabajo">
                                                <?php

                                                    $item = null;
                                                    $valor = null;

                                                    $orden = ControladorOrdenTrabajo::ctrMostrarOrdenTrabajo($item, $valor);

                                                    foreach ($orden as $value) {

                                                        echo '<a class="dropdown-item"
                                                   href="#">' . $value["codigoOrdenTrabajo"] . '</a>';

                                                    }
                                                ?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
```

Comment: Puedes agregar tu HTML para poder ejemplificar, gracias.

Comment: Listo compa adjunte el html, ayudame porfavor